Ubuntu screen is locked - inactivity - not turn on
When Ubuntu screen is locked, locks after a very few minutes of inactivity, and I am unable to unlock it or turn on back. The locked screen does not respond to mouse clicks or keyboard inputs. I had restart the PC, and I have to do it everytime. How to solve this problem?

Ubuntu 18.04 has reached end of support. Please install 24.04

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.

Is it locked; can you switch to text terminal OR give the kernel direct commands bypassing any locked/stuck GUI using SysRq commands... Even if the GUI is broken/frozen, you should still be able to safely shutdown/command the kernel, and if you cannot (such as a kernel panic) that has given you useful detail in finding a problem you should be addressing... You're off-topic here now with your EOSS (or EOL release, depending on unstated architecture your release maybe EOL or EOSS) as 18.04 is supported now by Canonical only.
